# Adaptive/Expandable Recyclerview for a questionnaire

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

**Info**:
I'm making an app that contains a questionnaire with Yes/No Checkboxes as answers. The questionnaire is made with RecyclerView, and each question with a CardView. The CardView contains a TextView (question text) and two Checkboxes (Yes and No box).

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/caseInfoItem
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
    app:cardElevation="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cameraView">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/questionText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/round"
            android:ems="27"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Yes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/no"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/checkYes"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/No"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/no"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/checkNo"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkYes"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
            android:button="@null"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/questionText"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkNo"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
            android:button="@null"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/Yes"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**Goal & Question**:
Depending on the answer, my list of questions should expand with one or two CardViews at a specific position (index).

*Example*: If I answer 'Yes' to a question (check the Yes box), another question, related to the answered one, should appear underneath on my RecyclerView. ***To be clear:*** Not a the end of the list, but underneath the specific question I just answered.

***How??***

There's the sample of my *Adapter* and *questionnaire Activity*:

```
public class CreateCaseInfoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CreateCaseInfoAdapter.CaseHolder> {

ArrayList<String> list;
CustomYesCheckListener yeslistener;
CustomNoCheckListener nolistener;

public CreateCaseInfoAdapter(ArrayList<String> list, CustomYesCheckListener yeslistener, CustomNoCheckListener nolistener) {
    this.list = list;
    this.yeslistener = yeslistener;
    this.nolistener = nolistener;
}

public CreateCaseInfoAdapter(ArrayList<String> list) {
    this.list = list;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public CaseHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.create_case_info_item, parent, false);

    return new CaseHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final CaseHolder holder, final int position) {
    String _item = list.get(position);
    holder.mSpgText.setText(_item);

    holder.mCheckYes.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                holder.mCheckNo.setChecked(false);
            }
            yeslistener.onCheckClick(holder.getPosition(), buttonView, isChecked);
        }
    });

    holder.mCheckNo.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                holder.mCheckYes.setChecked(false);
            }
            nolistener.onCheckClick(holder.getPosition(), buttonView, isChecked);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

class CaseHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public final CardView mView;
    public final TextView mSpgText;
    public final TextView mYes;
    public final TextView mNo;
    public final CheckBox mCheckYes;
    public final CheckBox mCheckNo;


    public CaseHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        mView = view.findViewById(R.id.caseInfoItem);
        mSpgText = view.findViewById(R.id.questionText);
        mYes = view.findViewById(R.id.Yes);
        mNo = view.findViewById(R.id.No);
        mCheckNo = view.findViewById(R.id.checkNo);
        mCheckYes = view.findViewById(R.id.checkYes);

    }
}
```

}

```
public void createQuestions() {

    switch (mCase.getReportType().toLowerCase()) {
        case "BIO": // Ignore this
            final ArrayList<String> arrayList = questionsBio(); // method creates a list with 'hardcoded' questions.

            adapter = new CreateCaseInfoAdapter(arrayList,new CustomYesCheckListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckClick(int position, CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (position == 0) {
                        String test = "TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST!!!";

                        if (isChecked) {
                            arrayList.add(1, test);
                            adapter.notifyItemInserted(1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, new CustomNoCheckListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckClick(int position, CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        Toast.makeText(CreateCaseInfoActivity.this, "No", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            recyclerView.setMinimumHeight(Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension
                    (TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, calculator(arrayList), getResources().getDisplayMetrics()))); // calculator method here!
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            break;
```

I know, that I might not be using my RecyclerView the way it's supposed to be used, as I'm setting the minHeight to be the length of all CardViews in my list.

**CustomListeners**:
I've made two custom listeners. One for each Checkbox. I'm doing this, so it's possible to implement an action to each Checkbox (and it works).

**So**, I've tried with adapter.notifyItemInserted(index position) and adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() and logically the last method does not work, as it reloads the whole list, and therefore uncheck my answer.

Any suggestions/ideas?

This is my first question ever asked on this site, so any kind of feedback would be appreciated.

**EDIT** **ANSWER**: For some reason I made it work with adapter.notifyItemInserted(index position). Somehow it works now. The reason might be, that I had a brainfart and wrote notifyItemSelected instead... Anyways, I hope this may helps others out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason I made it work with adapter.notifyItemInserted(index position). Somehow it works now. The reason might be, that I had a brainfart and wrote notifyItemSelected instead... Anyways, I hope this may helps others out there.